# How to go live with the PayPal API Xcode

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, paypal, live

My current code is as below:

```
PayPalPayment *payment = [[PayPalPayment alloc] init];
payment.amount = [[NSDecimalNumber alloc] initWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.2f",totalCost]];
payment.currencyCode = @"GBP";
payment.shortDescription = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Order ID : #%@", orderNumber];

// Check whether payment is processable.
if (!payment.processable) {
    // If, for example, the amount was negative or the shortDescription was empty, then
    // this payment would not be processable. You would want to handle that here.
}


// Start out working with the test environment! When you are ready, remove this line to switch to live.
[PayPalPaymentViewController setEnvironment:PayPalEnvironmentProduction];

// Provide a payerId that uniquely identifies a user within the scope of your system,
// such as an email address or user ID.
NSString *aPayerId = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@_%@",[nameField.text stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@" " withString:@""], orderNumber];

// Create a PayPalPaymentViewController with the credentials and payerId, the PayPalPayment
// from the previous step, and a PayPalPaymentDelegate to handle the results.

paymentViewController = [[PayPalPaymentViewController alloc] initWithClientId:<live credentials>
                                                                receiverEmail:<recievers email>
                                                                      payerId:aPayerId
                                                                      payment:payment
                                                                     delegate:self];



// Present the PayPalPaymentViewController.
[self presentViewController:paymentViewController animated:YES completion:nil];
```

I registered the app with paypal, I got this response:

"Congratulations! The application,  you submitted to the PayPal Developer Network, has been approved!
You are now ready to go live!

In order to go live with your application, please ensure you:
Replace the Test App ID with your live App ID in the code.
Your Live APP ID is: 
Make sure you replace your Sandbox API credentials with your live API credentials.

Need Help?
File a ticket with Merchant Technical Services at https://www.paypal.com/mts/"

Where do I put the live app id? what code do I change? what is the app id, is it the app id in itunes connect??

Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

in below method

```
paymentViewController = [[PayPalPaymentViewController alloc] initWithClientId:<live credentials>
                                                            receiverEmail:<recievers email>
                                                                  payerId:aPayerId
                                                                  payment:payment
                                                                 delegate:self];
```

replace "live credentials" with your app's client id and app id is your paypal app id so at the time of completion you must be provided with your app creation with it's id have a look at your paypal account you'll find it.

Comment: Hi thanks, I put I my live credentials. I have got my live app id from PayPal begins with AP-..... Etc. I am confused as it says put this into your code. Where in the code does the live app ID go? Is it the bundle identifier, does it go in the actual class, or do I change something at the PayPal side. Thanks